# EF entity.attach does not work

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have an entity retrieved from db as follows

```
using ( var ctx = new Mycontext() )
   return ctx.MyGroups.First( // query );
```

this is bound to UI and updated on user save action as follows

```
using ( var ctx = new Mycontext() )
{
    ctx.MyGroups.Attach(o); // verified object o is updated 
    ctx.SaveChanges();

}
```

However the db is NOT updated

Environment is .net 4.0, db is sql compact 4

Any help on what could be missing/wrong ?

Comment: yes, add works and have multiple records added

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you attach objects to the context, their default state is Unchanged, you should force the update by setting `DBContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;` And only after that call `DBContext.SaveChanges();`

Answer (score 0):

`Attach` method relies on primary key to attach the entity to object context. What seems to me is that when your object is changed from the view and model bound your primary key value is missing in the updated object.

Comment: The primary Key is never changed, that being said, i changed only 1 detail level field and tried to save it but not saved ! this is using Sql compact so wondering if there's a way to debug !!

Comment: its not user who is supposed to change the primary key. In edit scenario we sometimes forget putting hidden field for primary key field which results in default value assigned to primary key field on model binding. Have you checked on Post that your primary key property is containing correct value?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Ciobanu Ion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1160440/ciobanu-ion), here is your solution:

```
using ( var ctx = new Mycontext() ) 
{ 
    ctx.MyGroups.Attach(o); // verified object o is updated  
    ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(o, EntityState.Modified);
    ctx.SaveChanges(); 

}
```

*EDIT* As of EF 6, the above solution doesn't work.
Instead, use the following:

```cs
using ( var ctx = new Mycontext() )
{
    ctx.MyGroups.Attach(o); // verified object o is updated 
    ctx.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Not wokring anymore for EF 6, use this instead: ctx.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;